# How to loop in a mouse event?

Tags: java, mouseevent

How would would I loop mouse events? For example, I want to print out the x and y coordinates of the mouse position five times only. Any ideas how to do this?

EDIT - I am sorry if I wasn't too clear. I don't want to print out the same coordinates five times- I am supposed to record the coordinates of where the user clicks on my JPanel. However, I don't want to record it every time the user clicks - I only want to record the coordinates a certain number of times, say, I want to record five different coordinates. After 5 clicks, the program stops recording. This is my code so far:

```
private void getcoordinates(MouseEvent e){   
System.out.println(e.getX()+" - "+e.getY());
 }    


private void recordCoordinates(final int x){
addflagpanelRight.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    //call the getcoordinates function -
    //now loop the getcoordinates function for each "x"??
```

}

```
   //Empty definitions
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {}
    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}  
    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}   
    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}

});
}
```

Every time I try to loop the getcoordinates function I just get the same coordinates for each x. If x was set to 3, then when it loops 3 times, it prints 1 set of coordinates 3 times. Yes, I do realize the problem here, but how do I get around this?

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: Read the documentation for the Mouse event: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html If you want to show something x times, use an auxiliar variable to count.

Comment: Edited the above, have posted my code.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you need that, but it won't be so helpful. Because, movements of mouse are counted on every fraction of a second or nanos. So counting for *five* movements will lapse in an eye winks time.

Instead I suggest you change it to *five* location points. So that whenever you move your mouse pointer on those locations, you can display mouse co-ordinates.

To do that you need no looping but identifying the object on which you want to show the co-ordinates.

Comment: I see, but I still can't resort to manually adding points because I need the coordinates to be completely user defined. I can't predetermine every location point

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I am wrong, you want to print mouse position(x,y) five times. So in that case you add a mouse listener to the container where you want to listen and check that if already prints 5 times or not! and create a class variable for that check.

```
private int i=0;
...
addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() { 
      public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) { 
        if(i++<5)
           System.out.println(me.getX()+"||"+me.getY()); 
      } 
});
...
```